# With Power Shell, can I copy a file with series of name?

Tags: powershell, copy

Well, what I expecting is.. copy one file multiple times and at the same time customize created file name like 690, 691, 692, ..something like that.

After a few search, I sense it may possible .. but still don't know how..

Comment: so ... what have you tried? what did not work as expected? ///// as a hint - the `Copy-Item` command lets you give a new name to the copied item. [*grin*] there is also the `Rename-Item` cmdlet ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a shot at it.

```
echo hi > file
690..699 | foreach { copy-item file file$_ }
dir



    Directory: C:\Users\me\foo


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         8/2/2020   1:56 PM             10 file
-a----         8/2/2020   1:56 PM             10 file690
-a----         8/2/2020   1:56 PM             10 file691
-a----         8/2/2020   1:56 PM             10 file692
-a----         8/2/2020   1:56 PM             10 file693
-a----         8/2/2020   1:56 PM             10 file694
-a----         8/2/2020   1:56 PM             10 file695
-a----         8/2/2020   1:56 PM             10 file696
-a----         8/2/2020   1:56 PM             10 file697
-a----         8/2/2020   1:56 PM             10 file698
-a----         8/2/2020   1:56 PM             10 file699
```

Comment: ok I didn't know that powershell is replace of batch program.. thanks and its very helpful. I just can't imagine I can use foreach inside command..